# how to check the validity of the H matrix correctly

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, sift, feature-descriptor

i am making image matching using SIFT algorithm, and i compute th homography matrix to know whether there is a valid correspondence between the object and the scene or not. the method "isValidHMatrix" posted below is how i check if the H matrix is good or not,as posted [in this question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2588/check-if-homography-is-good/), i calculate the determinant of the top-left 2x2 matrix in the H matrix and if the determinant is >= 0 then it is good otherise the H matrix is bad.

but when i applied that concept to find the match between some objects and scenes i got the below posted results as images:

please let me know how to check the validity of the H matrix correctly

**results**:

```
for image 1: the object is part of the scene, but i got "invalid HMatrix,   
det(H): -8.978588811689873" 

for image 2: the object is not part of the scene, but i got "valid HMatrix, 
det(H): 3.32362768456779" 

for image 3: the object is not part of the scene, but i got 
"goodMatchesList.size() < 4 points" 

for image 4: the object is part of the scene, but i got "valid HMatrix, 
det(H): 0.153917265625088" 

for image 5: the object is part of the scene, but i got "valid HMatrix, 
det(H): 1.0012971075010808" 

for image 6: the object is part of the scene, but i got "valid HMatrix, 
det(H): 0.0037162733516824488" 

for image 7: the object is not part of the scene, but i got "invalid 
HMatrix, det(H): -2.397038481177457E-6" 

for image 8: the object is not part of the scene, but i got "valid HMatrix, 
det(H): 0.0"
```

**code**:

```
private boolean isValidHMatrix(Mat hMatrix, String token) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //double det = Core.determinant(hMatrix);
    double det = Core.determinant(hMatrix.submat(new Rect (new Point(0, 0), new Point(2, 2))));

    if (det >= 0) {
        Log.V(TAG, "isValidHMatrix", token+"_valid HMatrix, det(H): "+det);
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.V(TAG, "isValidHMatrix", token+"_invalid HMatrix, det(H): "+det);
        return false;
    }

}
```

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]
[image: img4]
[image: img5]
[image: img6]
[image: img7]

Comment: Were you able to find some solution